# Pycharm error: Error loading package list: Status:404

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I want to install the tensorflow packages, but when I add the url: 
https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.3.0-py2-none-any.whl/ 
link in the Manage Repositories. 
But there is nothing to show in the Available Packages, and there is error

```
(Reload List of Packages): Error updating package list: Status:404 as shown the image.
```

Could anyone help me solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've made a typo. Try this URL (no trailing slash): https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.3.0-py2-none-any.whl

If the error persists (which will look like a PyCharm bug), do this from the command line:

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade \
 https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.3.0-py2-none-any.whl
```